# ubuntu serial port on VirutalBOX (virtual machine)

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port

I have ubuntu runing on window 7 host. 
I have noticed that there's about 1.3 seconds delay between RX (The receive line) blinking on TTYS0/COM1 and my software to receive the message that came through the port.
Is there a way to reduce this? 
with this delay, the software is thinking that the slave accross the rs232 line is timing out...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to increase amount of memory and CPU that is needed to run your virtualbox
also you can run the vritualbox by disable desktop composition !

Comment: Howa, thank you for your reply. So is this a memory issue? nothing else can be done? no setup of somekind? I am running VBOX with 1024MB RAM (out of 4GB) and 15 GB space allocated to the Virutal machine, with an intel Dual core 2.3 GHz. That should be enough no?

Comment: even this i think you'll have a delay !
the best can be done is to install ubuntu on your hard drive(not using any tools) so you'll get the high performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do some of operation before receive your request just doit  after recive it try this or
try to use an thread in your application to let it goes faster than :)

Comment: mm actually no, I have a funtion that sends the request then waits for the answer and if(when) it timesout it'll throw an exeption. This is happening in the main thread...

Comment: ok, maybe not on the client side the delay happened maybe on server side before you send the response, what i mean the process you do it before send the response maybe take a high time :)

Comment: I can tell that I received the message almost instantansiously after the request is sent, because I can see both TX and RX leds blinking almost at exactly the same time....so the delay is not from there..